# What will be the shape of this graph at $t= \frac {T}{4}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

Consider the following variation with distance x and displacement y of the string at $t=0$
[image]

Then what will the shape of the graph be at $ t= \frac {T}{4}$?

My Attempt: I feel that the peaks of Graph 2 will become the zeroes of the new Graph. But I can't even guess the motion of the zeroes of the Graph2.

Is there a logical way to determine the motion of these points on the String?

Comment: After T/4 you move to the right by a quarter of a wavelength, so your $x=0$ now occurs at the first trough. The zeros indeed do not move, they are *nodes* of the wave.

Comment: @lemon I can figure out the equation of the wave $y=-2 sin( \frac {2*pi} { \lambda}x)$. And "hsnee" I have understood your point. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a standing wave of a propagating wave? The two have different equations so the answer will be different.

Comment: @JohnRennie This is a travelling wave.

Comment: In that case the equation is $y = \sin(2\pi x/\lambda - 2\pi t/T)$. Substitute $t = T/4$ and you have your answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie why is there $-2 \pi t /T$ term in the expression?

Comment: The wave is a function of both $x$ and $t$. If you take a constant position, i.e. constant $x$, then you'll find the amplitude varies sinusoidally with time. Alternatively if you choose a fixed time (this is what is shown in your graph) then the amplitude varies sinusoidally wth $x$. That's why you need both $x$ and $t$ inside the $\sin$ function. See [the Wikipedia article on plane waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave) for more details.